# Ajax method won't work any longer when passing ICollection in model from controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to list all `Courses` for specific student. However, I'm having problem sending `ICollection` list to Ajax method. When I do, nothing happens and I get the error message(in chrome):

> http://localhost:25237/Home/Test 500 (Internal Server Error)

If I comment/remove `Courses = readStudent.Courses`(a`ICollection` of `Courses`), my Ajax method then works as intended(without courses).

```
public ActionResult Test(Guid id) {

        var readStudent = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        var results = new StudentVm {

            FirstName = readStudent.FirstName,
            LastName = readStudent.LastName,
            SchoolName = readStudent.School.Name,               
            Courses = readStudent.Courses  //Icollection, works if I remove this line.
        };

        return Json(results);
    }
```

My Ajax code:

```
 $.post("/Home/Test", { "id": id },
     function (data) {
         if (data) {    

             $("#testDiv").append($('<div class=\"studentInfo\"> ' +
             '<br/> ' +
              <b>Student: </b>' + data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName +
              '<br/>' +
              '<b>School: </b>' + data.SchoolName +
              '<br/>' +
              '<b>All courses: </b>' +

               $.each(data.Courses(function(index, item) { allCources += '<b>' + item + '</b>'; })

               +'</div>'));

         }
    });
```

In the view I need to access the `Name` and `Description` property of `Course`

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

> System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected
>   while serializing an object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Student_32DDE9D84FE99EFF8907954351AD1F1A8162A0B565198DD8C7B4B25E2330BB98'.

Student model(created by EF):

```
public partial class Student {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Student() {
            this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
        }

        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }            
        public System.Guid SchoolId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Started { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Ended { get; set; } 

        public virtual School School { get; set; }    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }
```

Course model(created by EF)

```
  public partial class Course {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Course() {
            this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        }

        public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Classroom { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

My ViewModel to pass to View:

```
public class StudentVm {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: It means that your `Courses = readStudent.Courses` is throwing an exception. Debug your code.

Comment: Maybe it's a circular reference you can select one of the atributes of course like 'name'

Comment: Edit your question with the actual error and show your models and the properties of `Courses` that you want to include in the view. You need to create an anonymous object to avoid the circular reference (the error is because `Course` contains a property for `Student`)

Comment: Is why you are passing all the model choose only some attributes of the class course can you show your classes?

Comment: You still have not shown the `Course` model and which properties in that model you want to display in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added my models of `Courses` and `ViewModel`. By anonymous object, do you mean I should create a new List outside `var results = new StudentVm { `, and then pass the `courses` via the new list?

Comment: No, you added the `Student` model (which is needed) - but you need to show the `Course` model as well (and indicate which of those properties you want to display in the view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke My mistake. Added it now. Sorry about that.

Comment: And which property (or properties) of `Course` do you want to display in the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Just the name and description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown because `Course` contains a property for `Student` - the `JavascriptSerializer` tries to serialize `Course` which contains `Student` which contains `Course` which contains `Student` and so on (you would run out of memory if it continued).

You need to return only those properties of `Course` which you need in the view, so the `Courses` property of `StudentVM` should be a collection of another view model containing only properties you need, or alternatively just pass an anonymous object back to the client

```
var student = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
var results = new
{
    FirstName = student.FirstName,
    LastName = student.LastName,
    SchoolName = student.SchoolName,
    Courses = student.Courses.Select(x => new
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Description = x.Description
    })
};
return Json(results);
```

alternatively, if you want to use view models, then they will need to be

```
public class StudentVm
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    ....
    IEnumerable<CourseVM> Courses { get; set; }
}
public class CourseVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller code will be

```
var student = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
var results = new StudentVm
{
    FirstName = student.FirstName,
    LastName = student.LastName,
    SchoolName = student.School.Name,               
    Courses = student.Courses.Select(x => new StudentVM
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Desription = x.Name
    }
};
return Json(results);
```

and in then in the view, you will need to change the code in the `$.each()` loop to access each property of `Courses`

```
$.each(data.Courses(function(index, item) {
    allCources += '<b>' + item.Name + '</b>'; // and item.Description
})
```

Alternatively, consider using the far better and more powerful [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serializing data, which has options for setting how circular references are handled.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having error message "`Cannot implicitly convert type 'system...IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string Name, string Description>>' to 'System....ICollection<..CourseVm>"`.  I created a `CourseVm` for `Name` and `Description` only.  I also changed to `public virtual ICollection<CourseVm> Courses {get; set;}` inside `StudentVm`. Anything I've missed?

Comment: You not using the code I showed your in the answer! There is no reason to create a separate view model, but I will edit the answer to show you how to do it

Comment: Oh! You removed StudentVm near result! That's might be it. I thought it was just the Courses line. Sorry!

Comment: See edit for using view models (but there is no real need to do that - its just going to be serialized to json anyway - the browser has no concept of your view models)

Comment: It works now. Sorry for the inconvenience, I thought I used your code but I missed to remove `StudentVm`, silly me. Thank you very much for your well detailed explanation :)